# How to pin a guest page in memory in KVM?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I am doing stuff in KVM memory. I noticed that sometimes `kvm_mmu_notifier_invalidate_range_start()` would be called and then `kvm_unmap_hva_range()` then `drop_stpe()`, which would set a certain spte to zero. I guess there is a change in the mapping from HVA to PFN in the QEMU, so it need to invalidate those sptes pointing to those PFN, right?
I did some CoW mechanism to the spte, so `drop_spte()` made it difficult to work. Can I pin a page in memory so that the mapping from its HVA to PFN will not be changed? I want to pin a page when I CoW a guest page so that it will not be dropped accidentally.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess kvm_get_pfn() can be used to pin a pfn. You can use gfn_to_pfn() to get the pfn corresponding to gfn. To unpin the page you can use kvm_release_pfn_clean().

Comment: Thanks! I used kvm_get_pfn() to those pfn when I CoW them. However I could still see that some of them would be dropped.

Comment: These could be MMIO pages. You can try get_page(pfn_to_page(pfn)) for these pages.